# Why we dont have to use Autowired in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, autowired

I work as a intern somewhere and they said you dont have to use autowired there. They said search for it but i couldnt good explanation about it.

```
public class MedicineController {
    
    private IMedicineService iMedicineService;
    
    //I used @Autowired here
    public MedicineController(IMedicineService iMedicineService) {
        this.iMedicineService = iMedicineService;
    }
```

Comment: Did you use @Autowired to annotate the parameter IMedicineService ?

Comment: If you have only one constructor, there is no need to add @Autowired, spring will consider it as a required injection under the hood.

Comment: No i didnt use @Autowired in IMedicineService

Comment: The version of Spring you are using is smart enough to understand that it should inject an `IMedicineService` bean automatically into your `MedicineController`. The `@Autowired` annotation is not necessary. (It used to be required here for older versions of Spring).